# Why my contextProcessor doesnt work for all templates? django 2.2.1

Tags: python, html, django

As the title says, I have set an input processor but it does not work for all the templates of my page, just for some of them but not for all.

I have created the context_processor.py inside of my app.

```
def categories_processor(request):
   enterprise = enterprisedata.objects.get(id=0)        
   return {'enterprise': enterprise}
```

I heard thats all that i need to do it.

But it some templates when i try to call it like for example:

```
{% block title %}
<title>{{enterprise.name}} | Carrito</title>
{% endblock %}
```

Doesn't work.

Any help? something that I am missing? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add that `context_processor` in your project `settings.py` file like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
       ......
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
               .........
                'yourapp.context_processor.categories_processor',
            ],
        },
```

Comment: My app is called "adminview" i put it like this adminview.context_processor.enterprise_processor, but it says No module named 'adminview'

Comment: @LuisBermúdez all you have to do is provide the proper path for your function 
      `def categories_processor(request):`

Comment: How can i do it? sorry i am new at django :(

Comment: Did you write the `def categories_proccessor(request):` inside the `your_app/context_processor.py` ? If so then this solution should work.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I put  'apps.adminview.context_processor.enterprise_processor' instead of 'adminview.context_processor.enterprise_processor' and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it in [**`context_processors`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) settings(inside `settings.py` file) in Django:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        'django.template.context_processors.media',
        'path.to.context_processor.categories_processor'
    ],
},
```